# How to identify this element?

Tags: html, css

There are two grey lines at the bottom of every blog post on my site (also 1 in the main index)

I can't find these using the "inspect" feature -- how do I remove them?

example post:

http://nickgray.net/curb-your-dog/

Answer (score 1):

The site is using CSS Pseudocodes. like :before and :after. It is a CSS property that focus on the beginning and ending of the tag. For example on the site.

```
#jp-relatedposts h3.jp-relatedposts-headline em:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 30px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

To remove that line. Just remove the `Border top style`or make it `display none`. Hope that i'm right on what line you are talking about.

```
#jp-relatedposts h3.jp-relatedposts-headline em:before{
    content: "";
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.blog .hentry, .archive .hentry, .single-post .hentry {
    border-bottom: 0px !important;
}

#jp-relatedposts h3.jp-relatedposts-headline em:before {
    border-top: 0px !important;
}
```

add these lines to you stylesheet.